# CakePHP: JQuery submit() returns a blank page

Tags: cakephp, jquery

I create a function in CakePHP controller class to process AJAX request. But I found different result when using CakePHP function and simple (Non-MVC) PHP code. My problem is when it goes to **submit()** process. When using CakePHP function it returns blank page.

Here is the AJAX request code that I use:

```
var userdata = {username : $("#UserUsername").val()};
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/mycakephp/users/login',
            data: userdata,                     
            success: function(data){                                    
                if(data==0){
                    alert("empty");                 
                } else {
                    $("#UserLoginForm").submit();                       
                }
            }               
        });
```

But when I pointed the url to external site like this:

> url: 'http://localhost/test/test.php'

Which **test.php** is a simple PHP code to handle request, submit process works fine.

Comment: http://localhost/mycakephp/users/login is it working fine?

Comment: have u looked the console?look response that u get in console.

Comment: if I use CakePHP debug console, it shows debug timer info.

Comment: on your controller, try: debug($_REQUEST);

Comment: use your browser console to check ajax request and response.

Comment: @ArunKillu it show like this: NetworkError: 404 Not Found "http://localhost/mycakephp/users/login"

Comment: then your server path is wrong dear

Comment: I'm sure that the path is correct! It also contained this error: "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: do you use the SecurityComponent ? If this is the case, it may blackhole the request, because the form is not created by Cake and the names of the data you post are not following Cake standards

Comment: @nIcO I think it is. So what I have to do? disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, if you use the SecurityComponent, you could disable POST validation on the login action. In your UsersController, add this:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent :: beforeFilter();

    switch($this->request->params['action'])
    {
        case 'login':
            $this->Security->validatePost = false;
            $this->Security->csrfCheck    = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

But off course you loose the value added by the SecurityComponent on the login action.

Comment: Thanks @nIcO, but this one works for me: `if(isset($this->Security) && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
   $this->Security->enabled = false;    
  }`

Comment: It is another way to do the same thing: disabling the SecurityComponent. But in your case you do it on all actions. I would still recommend to do it on specific actions, in order to disable it only when it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your code looks bizarre to me: There you have a login form, you send  using ajax your username calling the Controller "UsersController" / function "login", and when you have an answer from this function, then you submit again another form ("#UserLoginForm") and send it again to the controller? You are sending two forms! Most probably this is not what you want. Correct me if I am wrong.

I guess what you want is just submit the UserLoginForm and wait for an answer, whatever it is OK or NotOK, and finally show this result.

You have two options to do this: either CakePHP way or your own ajax code using JQuery. I like to use both, depending on the user experience I want to get.

### 1. CakePHP way

Include JS Helper in the controler using the `public $helpers = array('Js');` and then create a Form in the view, using the submit from the JsHelper.

#### View

```
 <?php  
  echo $this->Form->create();
  echo $this->Form->input('username');
  echo $this->Form->input('whatever'); 

  // use the Js submit from JsHelper
  echo $this->Js->submit('Send', array(
        'url'=> array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'update' => '#update_ajax_div',
  ));
  echo $this->Form->end();
      // Next line is actually very important in order 
      //   to print the automatically created ajax code from JsHelper.
  echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
 ?>

 <div id="update_ajax_div">
this will be overwritten after submit.
 </div>
```

#### Controller

In the controller all the data in the form will be sent in the `$this->data[]` array. For example ***`$this->data['Users']`*** if this is the Model being used in the Form->create().

The code is pretty standard, except the layout, which must be set to ajax.

```
public function login(){

       // print the data being sent 
   $dataFromAjaxLink = $this->data[];
   $v = var_export($dataFromAjaxLink, true);
   $this->log("Ajax log:  ".$v, 'debug');

   if(isset($this->data['User'])){
       $user_name = $this->data['User']['username'];
        ...
       // do your stuff

   }
   // the answer must be ajax layout
   $this->layout = "ajax";
       // I like to use elements when using ajax, it keeps the folders clean
       //        in this example /app/View/Elements/display_ajax_result.ctp
   $this->render('/elements/display_ajax_result');

}
```

The content of this element will be printed in the div "update_ajax_div"

### 2. Pure Ajax way

The second version is done by manually typing ajax code in `<script>` tags. This solution gives you more freedom, allowing you to do more complex stuff, but the code is not so clean!

The following JQuery code must be inside some button/div/whatever event...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".someButton").click(function() {


      // create the json data to be sent
   var username = $(....).val();
   var dataString = ...

      // call ajax      
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
      // never type full paths as in your example. They are sources of errors!
      url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array(
            "controller" => "users", 
            "action" => "login")); ?>,
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
             $("#update_ajax_div").html(html);
      } 
   });

 ...
```

The controller is the same as the CakePHP way. Remember to add ajax layout.

I hope it helps you.